# Community ♦ Modified Posts Appearing on Homepage

Tags: support, old-questions, community-user, homepage, bump

Some Community user modified posts are appearing on the Stack Overflow homepage. These are old questions that have otherwise not been touched for some time. It's unclear what the reason is as I couldn't see any recent modifications shown on the questions or any of the answers - by the Community user or anyone else.

Here is [one of the posts in question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20025637/3899908).

[image: Homepage with Community modified posts]

Is this a bug?

---

Someone has, unhelpfully, posted a new answer on the example since I began to write this post. That is not the modification that caused it to first appear on the homepage though.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Community user randomly bumps old, unanswered questions to bring them to the attention of users and [maybe] get them answered. Note that in these circumstances, "unanswered" means that the question has no upvoted answers on it.

The word "modified" is misleading, and there is a [request to have it changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247392/please-do-not-lie-that-the-community-user-modified-the-question) so that it will match what actually happened to the post.

Comment: Empirically, Community prefers to bump questions with at least one answer (as long as they are "SE-unanswered", of course). It's rare to see a question without an answer being bumped (if it ever happens)

Comment: I assume Community ♦ also prefers to bump questions with a lot of views too. Google magnates!

Comment: Only questions with answers (but no votes) are eligible, @fam. I wrote up the full criteria somewhere on mse if you're interested.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/259867) is the official source; you may want to add this link to your answer, animuson.