# Don't put old inactive questions with answers that are not upvoted on homepage under "Unanswered Questions"?

Tags: discussion

The "Unanswered Questions" page (the "Unanswered" button next to "Ask Question") is flooded with old irrelevant questions (such as [inout parameter in closure crashes the Swift compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746913/inout-parameter-in-closure-crashes-the-swift-compiler)). Often, these are from (third-party) bugs that have been fixed, and they are usually abandoned by the asker.

Any input?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285978/community-modified-posts-appearing-on-homepage

Answer (score 2):

So...what you're saying is those questions don't have answers? And they're appearing in the "Unanswered Questions" list?

Sounds like things are working as expected.

So apart from that non-answer, if those questions are off topic, please close them as such.

If those questions are answerable, and you know the answer, why not answer them?

Comment: ... and if they have at least one acceptable answer, but no upvoted / accepted one, consider whether it's worth an upvote.