# If a very old question is not answered and not flagged

Tags: feature-request

So I have a question that is very old
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195034/every-5-sec-trigger-my-robot-to-back-up-and-turn
I have yet to get a response. In general what should be done about this? I know many questions are not answered and just drop off so should a periodic "bump" happen to old questions?

Comment: IIRC, the Community user does a periodic bump of questions that meet a certain requirement. But more effective would be a bounty. You have the rep to start a bounty.

Comment: I don't want to use my bounty since I no longer have a need for it. But I want it answered to improve the knowledge base of the community

Comment: Then I wouldn't worry about it too incredibly much- In general, if you don't still need the answer, I would just let it go until someone comes along who knows the answer.

Comment: Do nothing if you don't care about getting an answer. If you want it answered, do something that would improve its likelihood to be answered. If you leave it as is, it'l likely be deleted eventually assuming it doesn't receive any upvotes or answers.

Comment: `"I don't want to use my bounty since I no longer have a need for it. But I want it answered to improve the knowledge base of the community"` -- then still bounty it. You aren't restricted to using bounties on questions that you have a need for the answer. I myself have bountied several questions that are not my own, but that just piqued my curiosity.

Answer (score 6):

The feature you request already exists. But before we get to that, let's start from the beginning.

If you want a response, do something which increases your chances to get one.

Before anything else, look at your question. Is it good? Is it clear enough? Anything that might have caused it to go unnoticed? Address all issues that you see. Not only will you end up with an improved question, but at the end you also get a free bump, making it more visible again.

Let's say all is fine (in this particular case it isn't, really, improve your question) then you could go for a bounty. Give up some of your reputation to give your question some extra attention. With a bit of luck someone will see it and provide you with an answer.

Or rely on the Community User to [occasionally bump old and unanswered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285979/488657). That may just be enough to get it noticed. And that is exactly what you seem to request.

But if all that doesn't happen, or if you don't care enough to take any of these actions, all you can do is wait and see.