# 2020: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the past 12 months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we welcome 2021, and in keeping with tradition, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU1Al.jpg). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 1,196 | 1,512 |
| Users destroyed³ | 4,653 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 5,434 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 4,865 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 34 | 0 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 179 | 0 |
| User banned from review | 22,340 | 2,258 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Triage queue | 610 | 741,283 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 1,726 | 817,980 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 3,256 | 220,473 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 53 | 285,613 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 5 | 284,066 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Helper queue | 8 | 11,072 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 1,084 | 849,618 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 56,427 | 225,745 |
| Tags merged | 285 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 178 | 209 |
| Tag synonyms created | 273 | 86 |
| Tag highlight language set | 59 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 438 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 12 | 89 |
| Questions reopened | 2,544 | 12,197 |
| Questions protected | 57 | 4,288 |
| Questions migrated | 435 | 1,267 |
| Questions merged | 109 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 2,146 | 415,492 |
| Questions closed | 96,631 | 424,627 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 73,556 | 343,268 |
| Posts unlocked | 155 | 1,789 |
| Posts undeleted | 4,966 | 75,194 |
| Posts locked | 1,707 | 10,691 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 155,196 | 1,449,456 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 33,260 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 748 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 1,083 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 373 | 446,811 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 756,159 | 1,009,253 |
| Comment flags handled | 269,372 | 177,751 |
| Bounties canceled | 157 | 2 |
| Answers flagged | 4,313 | 345,227 |
| Answer flags handled | 268,537 | 80,891 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 1,884 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222020%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359735/208518)

A big thank you to [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) for writing the queries and script to facilitate fetching and posting this data to all the sites in the network, and to [Brian](https://stackexchange.com/users/459488/brian-nickel) for the subsequent work making the whole thing more user friendly.

Wishing everyone a happy 2021!

Comment: Are things like the 2 bounties cancelled performed by moderators that stepped down? AFAIK there's no way a normal community member can cancel a bounty

Comment: Moderators haven't bumped a single post, why is that?

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated because it's an automatic system thing that's associated to the Community bot...

Comment: **Over half a million questions closed** compared to 340k in 2019, a 50% increase year-on-year. If that isn't the clearest indication that there's a quality problem, I don't know what is.

Comment: @IanKemp well obviously Stack Overflow is becoming more popular... plus one could consider that a good thing, no? More questions being closed by both mods and users. Plus, ever since a moderator started reviewing the CV queue, more questions have been closed that would have normally entered the void. More questions are just being identified and acknowledged.

Comment: @IanKemp It's the clearest indication that [the close vote threshold was lowered from 5 to 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good), and that this change is having the desired effect.

Comment: Moderators don't have the ability to bump a post, @10Rep. As Jon says, that is *only* done by the Community user, which does have moderator privileges, but in this sense is acting more like a bot. The "Posts bumped" line item in the table does *not* refer to posts incidentally bumped due to edits. It's only talking about [the automated bumping that Community does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285979).

Comment: I would be interested in up/downvote statistics as well, either on question and on answers. I remember there was a problem that people were not motivated to downvote on answers, so I would like to see if that changed at least a little. Even the -1 rep means nothing (and usually returns on deletion), it seems it is a big deal for most users.

Comment: Does "Posts Deleted" / Footnote 6 also exclude Roomba deletions?

Comment: How does the community lock posts? Isn't that a mod thing?

Comment: How do normal users handle answer flags?

Comment: @Ruli AFAIK, you can do that using SEDE

Comment: @10Rep Mostly on review. Comment flags, when multiple users flag the same comment as NLN, for example, it gets deleted automatically. I think that several spam flags will auto-delete a post.

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated low quality review queue, triage, spam, rude and close flags.

Comment: @yivi Spam/abusive flags cause the post to get locked by Community when the threshold is reached.

Comment: @CodyGray If a hospital put out a press release saying "the number of gunshot wounds treated has increased by 50% thanks to us decreasing wait times from 5 to 3 minutes", the public response would not be "hey that's great", it would be "holy hell, why are there so many gunshot victims?"

Comment: Nah, the response is mostly just [that's business as usual](https://abc7chicago.com/chicago-shootings-2020-shooting-crime-stats-statistics/9250374/). Any time you put a textbox out there on the Internet, people are going to type nonsense into it. The trick isn't in finding a way to avoid the nonsense getting posted, it's in finding a way to deal with it. I think we have found one. We should continue to seek improvements to how we deal with it. It isn't the job of the hospital to reform the society to reduce the number of gunshot victims.

Comment: @IanKemp The problem is that the statistics tell us how many questions were closed (handled by community). We don't know how many needed to be closed but never got closed. There is a quality problem but the number of closed questions doesn't show that. It only shows us that we handled more than before. If anything we improved the quality a little by closing more questions, but there is still plenty that need to be closed.

Comment: much too much review bans

Comment: @ErikA can't the bounty offerer retract their own bounty? I would have expected more of these actually, when I see how many questions with a bounty should have been closed for various reasons.

Comment: @Kaiido Certainly not. Bounties are only retracted by mods, when questions are bad enough to need to be closed before the bounty expires. If you post a bounty, the rep is gone, you can't retract it. That's the source of my confusion. You can also see in earlier reports that this number has been 0, at least for the 2019 and 2018 one.

Comment: @ErikA that you don't get the rep refund is normal yes, for instance if it should have been closed because it's a dupe and someone pointed to the correct dupe thanks to the bounty, the bounty has done its job, but it can now be removed from the question and stop gathering now useless attention + prevent the correct closure of the question.

Comment: @IanKemp "If that isn't the clearest indication that there's a quality problem, I don't know what is." We could probably close many times more questions if only people would close vote more. Quality might be much, much worse than the official close rate of [16% of all new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359735/2020-a-year-in-closing) suggests.

Comment: @CodyGray "...the close vote threshold was lowered from 5 to 3, and that this change is having the desired effect." Yes, it looks like we were limited by close votes, not by close worthy questions.

Comment: @Trilarion s/might be/absolutely is/

Comment: Updated my spreadsheet (stats, totals, %change): **[Stack Overflow Yearly Stats](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1upnX9UX8ab8rde8DrGnOkZNnMqK0Qce0MgpLVTFUTUE/view)**

Comment: @CodyGray "The trick isn't in finding a way to avoid the nonsense getting posted, it's in finding a way to deal with it. I think we have found one." Have we really found one? Do we deal with all the nonsense that is posted? The number of close vote reviews done by the community seems to decline year over year. Even with a 3 close vote threshold that might not nearly be enough in the future. And single moderators working full days for free on that is also not sustainable, I guess.

Comment: The solution we have is not perfect, @Trilarion; I don't think I've ever argued or alluded to it being perfect. However, when I see that significantly more questions are getting closed this year than last year, I count that as significant progress. It certainly doesn't mean we've arrived at the end. There are plenty of questions that should be closed that fail to get closed. And new questions getting posted all the time that need to be closed, which is its own problem. If you have suggestions on how to reduce low-quality questions, please post a new question.

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry, I have no suggestion apart from some general optimize all involved processes further or some very doubtful hand-waiving machine learning possibility. More closures last year are certainly a success, but judging by the continually declining number of close reviews by the community year over year, I guess that the progress might not last. That's what I wanted to say.

Comment: Is the [What post get deleted and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296608/792066) going to be also updated?

Comment: @Dharman This datum only tells us that more questions are being closed. Without a metric for close-worthy questions, we can't definitely say that quality improved, even a little (because the number of close-worthy questions might have grown by more than the increase in closes).

Comment: Give me unilateral and unlimited delete privilege and I'll fix your quality problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis We call this privilege "diamond moderator". Keep your eye out for the next election. :-) Note that, even when you have unlimited access to the firehose, it's difficult to drink all of the water.

Comment: @CodyGray Haha, is it possible to get a negative number of votes?

Comment: Before I realized the context, the title seemed like a wildly, hilariously inapt description of 2020...

Comment: @IanKemp since there are multiple variables, perhaps a more reliable metric to compare would be the number of posts that got more than 3 close votes in 2019 and 2020?

Comment: @Anupam That's also not really comparable, since the Close votes review queue has become a lot more effective because of 3 votes being sufficient causing it to not be backed up to the point of most things aging away.

Comment: [Here they are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/1328704), @Braiam ;)

Answer (score 38):

> Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time?

Yes. And now my first question is: why is there such a huge difference in *Comments deleted* by Moderators?

| Action | Mod2020 | Mod2019 | Change | Comm2020 | Comm2019 | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 1,196 | 1,340 | -11% | 1,514 | 1,615 | -6% |
| Users destroyed³ | 4,653 | 4,305 | 8% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Users deleted | 5,434 | 4,155 | 31% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Users contacted | 4,866 | 4,475 | 9% | 0 | 0 |  |
| User suspensions lifted early | 34 | 45 | -24% | 0 | 0 |  |
| User review-bans lifted early | 179 | 64 | 180% | 0 | 0 |  |
| User banned from review | 22,340 | 3,023 | 639% | 2,258 | 4,004 | -44% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Triage queue | 610 | 34 | 1,694% | 741,283 | 1,239,611 | -40% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 1,726 | 2,940 | -41% | 817,980 | 1,141,695 | -28% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 3,256 | 223 | 1,360% | 220,473 | 185,719 | 19% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 53 | 219 | -76% | 285,613 | 343,007 | -17% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 5 | 25 | -80% | 284,066 | 282,584 | 1% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Helper queue | 8 | 9 | -11% | 11,072 | 31,119 | -64% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 1,084 | 89 | 1,118% | 849,618 | 804,290 | 6% |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 56,427 | 3,126 | 1,705% | 225,745 | 318,431 | -29% |
| Tags merged | 285 | 534 | -47% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 178 | 423 | -58% | 209 | 107 | 95% |
| Tag synonyms created | 273 | 534 | -49% | 86 | 77 | 12% |
| Tag highlight language set | 59 | 28 | 111% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Revisions redacted | 438 | 490 | -11% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Questions unprotected | 12 | 8 | 50% | 89 | 75 | 19% |
| Questions reopened | 2,544 | 1,235 | 106% | 12,197 | 9,112 | 34% |
| Questions protected | 57 | 141 | -60% | 4,288 | 6,039 | -29% |
| Questions migrated | 435 | 418 | 4% | 1,267 | 758 | 67% |
| Questions merged | 109 | 94 | 16% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 2,146 | 1,758 | 22% | 415,492 | 472,085 | -12% |
| Questions closed | 96,631 | 33,862 | 185% | 424,627 | 306,210 | 39% |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 73,556 | 45,195 | 63% | 343,268 | 430,080 | -20% |
| Posts unlocked | 155 | 147 | 5% | 1,789 | 574 | 212% |
| Posts undeleted | 4,966 | 3,325 | 49% | 75,194 | 70,345 | 7% |
| Posts locked | 1,707 | 432 | 295% | 10,691 | 8,517 | 26% |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 155,196 | 142,938 | 9% | 1,449,456 | 1,251,256 | 16% |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 0 |  | 33,260 | 34,352 | -3% |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 748 | 1387 | -46% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Comments undeleted | 1,083 | 1,770 | -39% | 0 | 0 |  |
| Comments flagged | 373 | 611 | -39% | 446,811 | 471,440 | -5% |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 756,159 | 6,075,670 | -88% | 1,009,253 | 981,980 | 3% |
| Comment flags handled | 269,372 | 244,261 | 10% | 177,751 | 227,661 | -22% |
| Bounties canceled | 157 | 227 | -31% | 2 | 0 |  |
| Answers flagged | 4,313 | 3,707 | 16% | 345,227 | 366,618 | -6% |
| Answer flags handled | 268,537 | 265,031 | 1% | 80,891 | 105,362 | -23% |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 1,884 | 1,568 | 20% | 0 | 0 |  |

Comment: Because [a script ran last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/2019-a-year-in-moderation#comment747023_392550) which deleted some millions of comments.

Comment: The script still runs, just at a slower pace now ... Also dang, that tags stuff really took a hit ...

Comment: If we deleted over 6 million comments every year, we'd eventually run out of comments to delete. It was necessary to pace ourselves. :-)

Comment: This is a really useful presentation, thanks for putting it together - it's certainly telling that a number of rather unsung moderator activities (tag cleanup, redactions, bounty oversight) have taken a palpable hit.

Comment: @Shog9 I feel the “bounties cancelled” and “posts redacted” metric changes are within the margin of error. “A few hundred a year” has plenty of room for fluctuations :-) Tag handling is a much more manual job and definitely took a hit when the most active moderator in that area suspended activity for a stretch.

Comment: Fair point, @Martijn - redactions jumped out at me simply because of the surrounding context: question volume increased this year esp with wfh, and I would have expected corresponding sensitive info mistakes to go up, but that's hardly guaranteed. Would need to dig into overall bounty activity to normalize that one, but pretty massive drop over the past couple of years.

Answer (score 23):

The (main) purpose of the LQP queue is to reduce our moderators' workload so that they have more time to review custom flags rather than deal with "me2" or "thanks you" answers all the time. When the community handles *less* than 1/4 of the answer flags, then you know something's wrong.

[image: Graph of LQP reviews as a percentage since 2016]

Therefore, I believe it's time to:

- [Merge VLQ into NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952)/[remove VLQ altogether](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340866) to avoid confusion.
- [Reduce "try this" answers by giving a helpful message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284563/10607772) to improve the quality of answers and warn the users who attempt flag them, possible linking to [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553) or [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370).
- [Improve the UX by adding more options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252217)

Ideally, if users understand which answers are NAA, then:

- DO NOT clear any NAA/VLQ flags when a post is edited or teach the reviewers what this button *actually* does.
- Decline flags raised on answers where the LQP consensus is "Looks OK" (similar to Leave Open in CVQ).

After that, the number of flags handled by the community should hopefully increase.

Comment: if most of mod handling goes to declining incorrect flags this may be good thing indeed. Mod declines carry warnings and flag suspensions - educational for incompetent / disruptive flaggers. Compared to that, "disputing" flags by regular users from review is toothless and useless

Comment: Maybe improve the queue as well, make it more obvious which answer should and shouldn't be deleted as many 2kers delete answers which aren't stricly NAA.

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated incorrect deletions from the LQP should be indeed rare because per my recollection when they [changed vote limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342632/839601) testing has shown that amount of 4 votes gets close enough to how posts are handled by diamond moderators - meaning same answers would be deleted by diamond mods

Comment: @gnat I still see plenty of "Recommend deletions" on posts that don't desevrve it

Comment: FWIW, vlq flags are probably a drop in the bucket compared to NAA; that's why they both go into the same queue. Love your 2nd suggestion though

Comment: The major purpose of VLQ flags is for moderators to get to lawyer over the definition of the word "very". Yes, please; let's *finally* get rid of it.

Comment: If we are going to remove VLQ then I would like to be able to flag the same post twice with NAA. It's the biggest advantage of having two flags.

Comment: I would say that's a scenario where you should just be raising a custom moderator flag, @Dharman. You're effectively asking a moderator to override the community's initial decision. That should just be expressed directly, not as an end-around with a second type of flag. (As a bonus, the moderator can review the actions taken by the reviewers in the first round and determine whether review suspensions are in order.)

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated data collected during testing of voting in LQP queue suggests that your observations do not indicate a problem worth worrying about

Comment: Hey look it's another answer with excellent suggestions that have been made for years but will never be implemented because SE Inc. hates us!