# 2021: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2021, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZntT.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 1,130 | 2,283 |
| Users destroyed³ | 17,851 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 4,826 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 4,793 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 29 | 0 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 86 | 0 |
| User banned from review | 280 | 1,658 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Triage queue | 9 | 434,241 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 2,008 | 529,477 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 46 | 122,593 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 120 | 284,004 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 14 | 244,962 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Helper queue | 0 | 1,974 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue | 120 | 193,593 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 12 | 447,614 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue | 16 | 142,421 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 125 | 213,104 |
| Tags merged | 180 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 102 | 160 |
| Tag synonyms created | 179 | 38 |
| Tag highlight language set | 43 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 833 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 3 | 72 |
| Questions reopened | 715 | 9,328 |
| Questions protected | 170 | 4,492 |
| Questions migrated | 402 | 1,282 |
| Questions merged | 98 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 2,973 | 359,525 |
| Questions closed | 22,640 | 432,352 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 37,327 | 324,808 |
| Posts unlocked | 144 | 645 |
| Posts undeleted | 4,597 | 67,159 |
| Posts locked | 544 | 13,139 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 114,668 | 1,417,149 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 32,928 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 816 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 658 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 385 | 451,292 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 403,458 | 867,568 |
| Comment flags handled | 266,989 | 184,705 |
| Bounties canceled | 147 | 0 |
| Answers flagged | 4,388 | 336,369 |
| Answer flags handled | 253,134 | 87,594 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 345 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2020: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404558/2020-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222021%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2022! ^_^

Comment: Updated comparison spreadsheet: [Stack Overflow Yearly Stats](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1upnX9UX8ab8rde8DrGnOkZNnMqK0Qce0MgpLVTFUTUE/edit)

Comment: @SamuelLiew Wow, that 283.6% increase on users destroyed really shows the scale of the spam plague.

Comment: Not sure how I feel about the decline in almost every action,  compared to last year

Comment: @Lino Some of the decrease in triage and such could be due to the first post and answer queues being created. But even then, its still a decrease.

Comment: Can you expand upon *"Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges ..."*. I thought privileges depend on reputation and that, in turn, depends on writing questions and answers. (A few reputation points come from ones first few edits.)

Comment: @AdrianHHH Time and effort is put into writing answers, questions, edits, etc. which in turn give reputation which in turn gives privileges, seems pretty clear.

Comment: @Nick The topic is moderation, the text I quoted implies that time spent doing moderation contributes to getting more privileges.

Comment: @AdrianHHH The topic is indeed moderation, but I read that point as a _thank you_, as in, "you've put in all this effort, you've unlocked the privileges, and you've used them, good job".

Comment: I wonder how much did the reopening of mobotics contribute to the increase in number of destroyed/deleted users...

Comment: we already have a process for auditing moderator actions.

Comment: I love statistics and data analytics! However, I'm a little disappointed at how few of my personal flags were handled compared to total site flags that were handled: while 702,863 of the 703,255 question and answer flags were handled (99.9%), only 126 of my 159 flags were handled (79.2%). 23 of the remaining unhandled flags were "aged away" (14.5%). I'm counting "helpful", "declined" and "disputed" among my flags as "handled", too. What's with that difference in numbers? I'd at _least_ expect my flags to approach 90% handled.

Comment: well, it depends on the kinds of flags, @SylvesterKruin. close flags for example likely age away far more often than any other kind of flag.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin See my "answer" below (this is "meta", of course, so it's just "discussion" rather than an "answer"), but my *theory* is that Flags are being considered "Handled" for the sake of this report when they are *placed* in the Review queue.  But as for how many reviews get *through* the review queue, as you've noticed, I think it's much lower.

Comment: Is this "_over the past 12 months_" from 13/01/2021 to 13/01/2022 or from 01/01/2021 to 01/01/2022?

Comment: @Lino Aside from everything else, many people had less time due to the global pandemic.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Updated my answer, which should explain the phenomenon we are seeing there.  Also see the Mod [answer to it on Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19893/1165986).

Comment: @Lino "Not sure how I feel about the decline in almost every action, compared to last year" Maybe quality of contributed content has increased or quantity decreased and less curation action were needed or it hasn't and less curation action were possible or a mixture of it all. We would need more context to answer this. Also if the numbers are small, fluctuations are high and it can happen that values decline just by chance.

Comment: It's the past calendar year, @holydragon, so 1/1/2021 to 31/12/2021.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Comparing your percentage (which is 33 in absolute numbers) to the percentage of the whole site is not a good comparison. Your personal percentages are always going to swing much more wildly than the whole site's _because_ of the huge disparity in size. When were your 33 still-outstanding flags raised, and were they custom mod flags that require investigation/escalation to the CM team? If they were raised in Nov/ Dec and were mod flags, it is not at all surprising if they are still pending.

Comment: @TylerH It makes a bit more sense, now that several (including yourself) have explained it, but it's still interesting. I suppose this means that the numbers above are not counting flags that have been raised, and not handled yet? The majority of my flags are not custom moderator flags; they are usually about low-quality questions. The 8 pending flags I have currently were all raised this year, so it's unfair to count them in my numbers; I'll re-post the percentages without counting the flags raised this year (although it's only 5%). The 23 aged-away flags were _all_ raised before Dec 1, 2021.

Comment: This is a re-post of the statistics in my [other comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415250/2021-a-year-in-moderation?noredirect=1#comment889280_415250), which included the flags raised in 2022, and thus is not a fair assertion of my handled flags. Here are the correct stats: of my 151 flags raised in 2021, 128 were handled (84.77%) and 23 were aged away (15.23%). This is still much less than the 99.9% in the stats above. Now I'm curious; what percentage of flags raised are custom-moderator flags? Why do close flags age away more often?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin most flags do not age away, only close and reopen flags, because of how the close and reopen vote review queues work. They used to be permanent, but Shog made the decision to make them (and close/reopen *votes* which are what your flags turn into after 3k reputation) age away many years ago, circa 2014/2015. The result is questions can naturally leave the review queues without having reviews "completed" (e.g. receiving 3 [at the time, 5] votes of either 'close/leave closed' or 'reopen/leave open').

Comment: *"The system will suspend a user when a user is recreated after being previously suspended."* But... does that mean that if one user is suspended on a network, when anyone else (aware or unaware of the suspended user) using that network creates an account, the suspended user would suffer the consequences?

Comment: @AnnZen from my understanding, when a user deletes their _profile_ for a particular site, then when they recreate the profile (using the same credentials/network account) the profile will still be suspended. I don't believe it's related to the network they're connecting from (although the users on that network _can_ be hit by the IP based rate limiting, that is however, AFAIA, separate from the suspension mechanism).

Comment: @Nick What I'm saying is, when a user is suspended, it's true that if they decide to create a secondary account *(to do things like ask questions)* while their main account is suspended, their main account's suspension should be prolonged, and the secondary account should be deleted. But due to the way such actions are detected, a user may have their account's suspension wrongfully prolonged whenever another person, who shares their network, creates an account during their suspension.

Comment: @AnnZen Those _actions_ aren't (to the best of my knowledge) automated in any way (although the checks likely are), so they wouldn't be covered by "the system" (community) due to the potential for error. IP addresses aren't precise enough to identify individuals so situations like that would require assessment by mods/staff and a suspension would only be handed out if they can be reasonably confident that something fishy is indeed going on. I would be hesitant to trust any stories of an innocent user having their main accounts suspension extended in the way you suggest.

Comment: @Nick *"and a suspension would only be handed out if they can be reasonably confident that something fishy is indeed going on"* And how confident is "reasonably" confident? Would there be anything fishy if the account (created during the suspension of the other account on the same network) made no interactions with the suspended account, and mainly asked questions?

Comment: @AnnZen I'm not a mod :-) I'm just making, IMO, reasonable assumptions on the process. You'd need one of them to weigh in on it.

Comment: @Nick I understand. My question was directed at the OP, who happens to be a mod.

Comment: What is _Bounties canceled_? What are reasons to cancel bounties?

Comment: @AlexGuteniev You bounty a question, and then a user whom you _really don't like_ answers the only answer, and you're just ***so*** desperate not to give them reputation that you cancel your bounty ;-).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin But only moderators can cancel bounties, and they won't agree to take the action if you simply "don't like" the only user who answered. SO is all about content, not people :)

Comment: @AlexGuteniev We primarily clear fraudulent bounties (extremely infrequent), and periodically bounties on off-topic posts that weren't closed prior to the bounty being placed. The latter does happen relatively regularly; 147 cancelled bounties means one every few days, and I'll go ahead and argue the majority of them are on off-topic posts. (letting them expire instead does happen, but it really depends on the mod, remaining duration, activity, etc.)

Comment: Not sure I contributed anything to this year's numbers anyway but it's gonna be a weird transitional year for me. I think the site, on the other hand, will get on just fine.

Comment: What was the amount of questions in 2021 overall?

Answer (score 21):

A "grand total" might be a nice addition, but it's easy to copy/paste into Excel and arrive at:

1,147,403 total Moderator actions in 2021.  Wow! And a big "Thank You" to the Mod team for your hard work!

Comment: But various actions aren't really comparable. Handling a suggested edit could be about a minute of work (or even less), but something like a suspension indicates a lot more work potentially (imagine having to investigate plagiarism across dozens of posts).

Comment: @Laurel Fair enough - Like I said "might be nice" ;-).  But regardless, my point is that's a lot of action taken by the Mod team, big or small, those actions add up and are appreciated.

Comment: And we have 23,202 users who got in trouble last year (that includes users suspended, destroyed, deleted, and banned). That's about 63 users getting in trouble per day on average, or about 3 per hour :-|. On the bright side, that's 11,933 users _less_ than 2020, which had ~96 users that got in trouble per day, or ~4 users an hour! Or _is_ that a good thing? I guess it depends on how you look at it....

Comment: @SylvesterKruin A matter of perspective, 'tis true.  And the spam problem (which often precedes deleted/suspected/destroyed accounts) seemed to get *much* worse in the last few weeks of the year.  Again, thankful for the moderation actions which cleaned these up, but yes, wish they weren't necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 17):

There were 2,973 questions, 385 comments and 4,388 answers flagged by moderators. I always considered moderators as flag handlers, not generators.
In what situations would moderator raise a flag? And who handles them?

Comment: We raise binding spam or R/A flags on posts, which immediately nukes the post. We can also flag comments as unfriendly so they become a part of the "paper trail". As those flags are binding, no one handles them. Those are the bulk of it. Additionally, you'd occasionally come across something you don't have the time to deal with at the moment, so you custom flag it to handle it later or have another mod pick it up.

Comment: In short, 'raised' flags by mods are also 'handled' flags by mods. Mods browse the site, too, not just the moderation tools pages :-) They can (and should) flag stuff the come across naturally (or unnaturally, which still needs flags/handling).

Comment: @TylerH I think that they need to raise a flag to be able to elevate issues to CMs too.

Comment: @Braiam That's certainly one vector. They also have chat, the Moderator Team, and probably some other methods, too.

Comment: @Braiam No, that works on a different system [since '16](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285899/269301).

Answer (score 3):

Can someone provide more detail on the "Question Flags Handled" and "Answer Flags Handled" stats.  They show right at 100% of the total flags were handled.

---

Edit/Update:  Zanna, a mod on Ask Ubuntu, provided the information [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19893/1165986) that explains this stat:

> A flag to close a post is considered to be handled if it is marked helpful. **This happens if the post receives at least one close vote**, regardless of the outcome of the close review.

So yes, it's entirely feasible that such a large percentage of Close flags result in at least one vote in the queue (either to Close or "Leave Open"), and as a result were "Helpful" or "Declined", and as a result of that, "Handled".

At the same time, it's entirely normal (and yet unfortunate) for a large number of *those* to never receive *enough* votes to make it all the way through the queue before the votes expire. Not an ideal situation, to be sure, but it at least explains the "Handled" stat.

---

We know that a number of these (at least questions) "aged out" (invalidated) of the review queue they were placed in as a result of the flag, right?  Does "Invalidated" count as "handled"? Should it?

I know that before I hit 3k and could cast Close votes, I flagged a number of questions that "aged out" of review.  I'd assume this is the case for a lot of users.

I adapted [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1541255) from one that was referenced in a chat on Ask Ubuntu with one of the mods.  It checks for Close Vote reviews that were invalidated after 4 days or 14 days, with the assumption that these were due to [expired votes per this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/902710).  It hit the max of 50,000 invalidated reviews in 2021.  This would seem to indicate to me that a large number of Close flags that get moved to the Close Vote Review queue are expiring, rather than being "handled."

Not that the Mods (and community) aren't doing a great job of curation and moderation, but is it fair to say that we *really* are at nearly 100% of question flags being handled?  It seems to me (based on 50k expired CV reviews) that there's still a lot of room for improvement that isn't indicated by a "near 100%" handled stat.

Comment: Flags can be carried over from year to year. Some of the flags raised in 2020 would have been handled in 2021. Like wise some raised in 2021 will be handled this year. Though the numbers aren't at 100%. There were 362135 questions flags handled and 362498 raised (that's 99.89%) and for answers 340757 and 339728 respectively (99.7%). It does, however, show that the mods are (more or less) keeping up with the volume.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I know that the numbers aren't *exact* due to some flags and their handling falling outside the calendar year. 
 That's negligible.  My point is that "Mods" only handled about 10% of the questions (but about 75% of answer flags).  The other 90% of the question flags were handled by the Community, either through review queues or automatic handling.  However, we know that questions "age out" of community review after 2 weeks and are marked "Invalidated".  It seems that those that age out are being included as "Handled".

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds "In need of moderator intervention" flags don't age-out. My understanding is that NAA and VLQ flags also don't age-out. The  NAA and VLQ lists, usually, don't get long enough to verify that, but the VLQ list is fairly long at the moment, which gives the opportunity to see they don't age-out after at least several/many days. Spam and R/A flags *can* age out after 4 days, but are never active for anywhere *remotely* close to that (i.e. usually minutes). Close-flags, like close-votes, do age out but those flags are not presented to moderators. They go to the CV review queue.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen - That's good info on the process flow.  And yes, it's primarily the Close flags that I think are getting invalidated, but according to the stats above, they would appear to be "handled" by the Community review at nearly a 100% rate.  It's mainly that particular stat that I'm questioning.  I think there's a SEDE query that might get me pretty close to the actual number that age out.  Zanna (mod on Ask Ubuntu) brought it up a while back in chat.  Let me see if I can adapt it.

Comment: @Makyen Added the SEDE query.  Unless the assumptions in my query are faulty (entirely possible, but again, based on one of the AU mods) it appears that more than 50,000 questions aged out of Close Vote review in 2021.

Comment: And just a small correction - I found the original query, and it didn't come from Zanna, but from another person who was in the chat with Zanna.