# Is there a chance to get the info why and which user was removed?

Tags: discussion, users

Usually we get the info that a user was removed with deduction of points.

I would like to know why and which user was removed?

Is this possible?

I am aware of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed

Comment: No, you can't find out either. A staff member or moderator *might* be able to find out, but considering that votes are meant to be private, this would break the fundament part of that. As for the *why*, if the user themselves chose the delete their account, then Stack Overflow would have no idea what their motivation was. If SO deleted them, likely it was due to them breaking the rules some how, which warranted their account being deleted.

Comment: [meta.se] related question: [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Comment: No. Mods and staff can see why an account was deleted, but mods cannot see which account was associated with a removal-connected reversal. We can guess if the account has cast enough votes to show up in mod tools, but we might get it wrong. But in general, we also _can't_ disclose who or why even if we could figure it out. Votes are also private; account deletion does not change that.

Comment: Also, not all accounts are removed by mods or staff. People delete their accounts regularly, and that's their right. I have no idea what was the case here (I couldn't find the account even if I wanted to), but say it was self-deleted; how does that help you? We don't require reasons when users delete their own accounts. There isn't even a field for it for Science:tm:. You'd have to reach out to them for the exact reason, and we can't provide the email. The most common user deletion reason is self-deletion as well, so odds you get no concrete answer are high

Comment: @Zoe stands with Ukraine. With your knowledge I would perhaps never asked, but I have no data what is going on. How may delete themselves, how many were deleted by staff etc... I am just curious and try to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: For 2021: [*Users deleted: 4,826*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415250/2021-a-year-in-moderation)

Comment: You can do an SE Reputation Audit on my app: https://se-reputation-audit.glitch.me/ that  wil have a category "User Deleted" with a link to the post where you lost a vote. That still doesn't tell you why or which users was removed but gives you at least the post(s) involved in the event. In case you interacted with that user in comments you might still find those comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even moderators cannot see which deleted user caused your loss/gain of reputation.

E.g., as a moderator viewing [your reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13321647/tarjae?tab=reputation&sort=time), the "User was removed" is not a link, and "learn more" is exactly the same as what you can see - a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed

> [image]

If you really wanted to, the only way is to become a Stack Overflow staff member with administrator privileges.