# 2022: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2022 (and where did January go, right?) and dive head first into 2023, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 626 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 232,543 | 74,552 |
| Answers flagged | 6,755 | 300,746 |
| Bounties canceled | 135 | 0 |
| Comment flags handled | 243,198 | 141,435 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 521,593 | 727,271 |
| Comments flagged | 964 | 383,400 |
| Comments undeleted | 1,068 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 1,617 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 33,204 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 131,012 | 1,281,827 |
| Posts locked | 720 | 16,612 |
| Posts undeleted | 4,864 | 55,476 |
| Posts unlocked | 357 | 724 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 36,609 | 255,393 |
| Questions closed | 35,745 | 373,154 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 4,533 | 292,090 |
| Questions merged | 85 | 0 |
| Questions migrated | 444 | 1,085 |
| Questions protected | 288 | 3,505 |
| Questions reopened | 1,118 | 6,887 |
| Questions unprotected | 5 | 53 |
| Revisions redacted | 1,119 | 0 |
| Tag highlight language set | 29 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 367 | 23 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 189 | 145 |
| Tags merged | 340 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue | 540 | 96,495 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First answers" queue | 61 | 350,878 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First questions" queue | 182 | 474,684 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Late answers" queue | 20 | 141,690 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue | 701 | 242,261 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Reopen votes" queue | 57 | 67,576 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue | 3,422 | 295,589 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Triage" queue | 19 | 241,011 |
| User banned from review | 542 | 1,089 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 85 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 57 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 8,487 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 4,010 | 0 |
| Users destroyed³ | 10,537 | 0 |
| Users suspended² | 3,132 | 2,683 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). Community can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2021: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415250/2021-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2023! ^_^

Comment: Any idea why "Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue" is lower than last year?

Comment: well, it was (roughly) the same % reduction from the prior year. Err... i skipped a year. but still, it's been dropping by large numbers every year recently

Comment: 1.4 million posts deleted... Presumably most are automatically deleted questions, about 30 days old(?).

Comment: Users suspended by mods: 177% increase since last year (1,130->3,132). *salutes mods (and flaggers) for their work. I wonder how much of that was just from December... I guess we became more active about finding and handling plagiarism too.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, Community-deleted posts would primarily be posts deleted by Roomba and posts deleted when a moderator deletes/destroys an account. It would probably also include spam/abusive-flagged posts.

Comment: @user And nearly 200% on escalations, wow.

Comment: "Bounties canceled: 135 (moderators) | 0 (community)" What does it mean to have a moderator cancel a bounty? I would think this would mean posts that get closed/deleted that have an active bounty, but that's got to be more than 135. Also, would the bounty placer get a refund of rep (I assume not)

Comment: @Samathingamajig It literally means that a moderator removed the bounty for a question, which refunds it to the person who set the bounty. This is commonly done when a question is off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for Stack Overflow, since the bounty being active prevents the question from being closed.

Comment: [Spreadsheet for comparison of all previous years' stats and %-change over time](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1upnX9UX8ab8rde8DrGnOkZNnMqK0Qce0MgpLVTFUTUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @CodyGray: are you saying this is not automatic? I would suspect, if a bountied question gets removed that the bounty gets refunded automatically. No need for moderator intervention for that.

Comment: @Dominique Yes, when a question with an active bounty is deleted, the bounty is also canceled and the reputation is refunded to the person who set the bounty. However, because bountied questions cannot be closed, it's unlikely that they're going to be deleted by anyone other than moderators. Mods remove plenty of bounties from questions manually (*without* deleting the question) in order to be able to close them as off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: CV queue at -54% this year is noteworthy.

Comment: Reopen took an even bigger dive. Are we just losing active curators without attracting new engagement from newer users?

Comment: It would be interesting to see these numbers in the context of total Questions asked and answers posted.

Comment: `Escalations to the Community Manager team 1,617 0` and here I always thought it was the community's job to escalate things and the moderator's job to de-escalate...

Comment: "*Escalations to the Community Manager team: 0*" does this not include the Contact Us form? I would count those as users escalating to the CMs.

Comment: Can edits be added to this table? That's a significant part of moderation

Comment: @TylerH: No, the Contact Us form is separate; I believe "CM escalations" only counts those escalations that are done by mods from the Mod menu on a user's profile.

Answer (score 34):

I always love seeing these numbers, I'm just here to waggle my eyebrows at them.

The suggested edit numbers surprised me a little, the mods seem to be pulling a lot of weight. It turns out this is because we've recently elected some absolute workhorses of the suggested edit queue. [SEDE query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1701034). Around 2/3 of those suggested edit reviews were done just by Henry Ecker and Ryan M alone.

That being said, Henry was called up to be a mod last month, and Ryan cracked out a couple hundred reviews before being called up early last year. So these reviews weren't necessarily performed by moderators, but performed by people who were chosen as moderators before the end of the year :)

And with that nit picked, *thank you everyone!*

Comment: Are you implying that the status of "moderator" does not apply retroactively?

Comment: @CodyGray It doesn't matter too much either way :P But I'd like to see SO predict which users will get elected as mods in the next few years and include their contributions under the mod column too