# 2023: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It’s that time of the year again! As we wave goodbye to last year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here might be aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks — folks like you. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference in ensuring Stack Exchange sites remain a valuable source of high-quality content on the web.

So as we say goodbye to 2023 (and January 2024… ahem) and move into 2024, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmN7M.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community User¹ | Community² | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 322 | 0 | 0 | 322 |
| Answer flags handled | 178,038 | 81,504 | 2 | 259,544 |
| Answers flagged | 6,881 | 7,369 | 249,314 | 263,564 |
| Bounties canceled | 80 | 0 | 0 | 80 |
| Comment flags handled | 143,582 | 86,027 | 2,096 | 231,705 |
| Comments deleted⁸ | 525,933 | 1,524 | 446,613 | 974,070 |
| Comments flagged | 812 | 10,970 | 221,224 | 223,006 |
| Comments undeleted | 837 | 0 | 0 | 837 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 1,187 | 0 | 0 | 1,187 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 32,612 | 0 | 32,612 |
| Posts deleted⁷ | 102,874 | 621,929 | 323,361 | 1,048,164 |
| Posts locked | 729 | 13,328 | 0 | 14,057 |
| Posts undeleted | 5,825 | 61 | 32,542 | 38,428 |
| Posts unlocked | 1,401 | 574 | 0 | 1,975 |
| Question flags handled⁶ | 23,141 | 111,327 | 40,275 | 174,743 |
| Questions closed | 23,894 | 212,438 | 51,680 | 288,012 |
| Questions flagged⁶ | 3,610 | 2,958 | 172,081 | 178,649 |
| Questions merged | 103 | 0 | 0 | 103 |
| Questions migrated | 289 | 950 | 0 | 1,239 |
| Questions protected | 89 | 2,148 | 1,511 | 3,748 |
| Questions reopened | 977 | 3,592 | 2,531 | 7,100 |
| Questions unprotected | 9 | 0 | 147 | 156 |
| Revisions redacted | 508 | 0 | 0 | 508 |
| Tag highlight language set | 13 | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| Tag synonyms created | 232 | 11 | 0 | 243 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 111 | 0 | 92 | 203 |
| Tags merged | 255 | 0 | 0 | 255 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Close votes" queue | 121 | 19 | 87,696 | 87,836 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First answers" queue | 10 | 1,179 | 223,968 | 225,157 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First questions" queue | 16 | 251 | 307,385 | 307,652 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Late answers" queue | 1 | 198 | 94,633 | 94,832 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Low quality posts" queue | 218 | 3 | 210,451 | 210,672 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Reopen votes" queue | 74 | 15 | 51,162 | 51,251 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Suggested edits" queue | 1,623 | 21,735 | 213,978 | 237,336 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Triage" queue | 3 | 387 | 162,100 | 162,490 |
| User banned from review | 89 | 0 | 644 | 733 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 9 | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 119 | 0 | 0 | 119 |
| Users contacted | 11,217 | 0 | 0 | 11,217 |
| Users deleted | 1,635 | 0 | 0 | 1,635 |
| Users destroyed⁴ | 6,654 | 0 | 0 | 6,654 |
| Users suspended³ | 5,931 | 2,458 | 0 | 8,389 |

#### Footnotes

¹ This refers to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² This refers to [the membership of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

³ The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

⁴ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁵ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁶ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). The community² can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁷ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁸ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2022: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422885/2022-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222023%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396299/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2024! ^_^

Comment: What does the number of closed questions by Community User (212,438) tell me? How is the Community User involved in closing questions? I know in the case of duplicates, when the OP agrees, it says closed by community bot, but that's certainly not 75% of all close votes.

Comment: Users can also self-close via Community based on close _flags_ @jps. That could account for part of it.

Comment: @TylerH Those seem like data points that could be obtained from SEDE without too much difficulty. If you're just looking for non-deleted Q&A, it's something that could be done by searching on the site (1,020,631 non-deleted questions; 1,048,938 non-deleted answers). If you want deleted posts, then a mod can get that through searching: (460,603 deleted questions; 222,380 deleted answers). A *very* rough data point for number of new users can be obtained from public on-site data (user # near end of year - user # near beginning of year): 2,277,333 (assuming sequential assignment of user numbers).

Comment: It would also be great to show revisions here. Editing is a huge part of user moderation. And the Community User even does its fair share of editing for things like CommonMark migration, http->https updates, etc.

Comment: @TylerH [via SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1816328), that is _roughly_ 821,064 deleted questions and 279,826 deleted answers.  This differs from the stats in the question by 52,726 total posts, presumably due to the fact that those stats "ignore[] numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action" (and also the SEDE query is not counting since-undeleted posts).

Comment: @RyanM Thanks, so we can see that roughly 44.4% of questions posted in 2023 were deleted by "community" actions. That helps inform that we have a significant signal-to-noise problem, AKA an ideal direction for the company to improve the quality of their primary product: Q&A. My gut reaction to that statistic is: it appears to be _far too easy_ to ask a question on Stack Overflow. Significantly increasing friction here will likely increase the quality of new posts, as significantly more effort will be needed. It seems particularly obvious if you compare these stats to those from Staging Ground.

Comment: @TylerH That's not _quite_ right: questions _deleted_ in 2023 were not necessarily _posted_ in 2023 (and in fact, due to the fact that the [abandoned question cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) takes effect after 365 days, quite likely were not).  Of questions _posted_ in 2023, [437,907 were also deleted in 2023](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1816329) (and from the same query, the corresponding number for answers is 220,736).

Comment: @RyanM I took Roomba to be included in the "numerous deletions that happen automatically". Though that revised number still shows a 30% deletion rate... that's still too high, IMHO.

Comment: For those that want to visualize this data, [here are the top five metrics that all have stats for the previous 5 years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxzGQ.png).

Comment: How did Community ("the membership of Stack Overflow without diamonds next to their names.") cause 644 "User banned from review" events? I would've thought that automated review suspensions would have been attributed to Community User (user -1). Am I misunderstanding that row? Or is that value in the wrong column?

Comment: These statistics don't tell me much. To make something meaningful out of it we'd need to know the number of active users over the same time period. Then it could also be compared with other years, given that the number of active users those years were known as well.

Comment: Otherwise we risk getting the same "statistics" as in the news: "The number of traffic accidents in NY have gone up with 5% during the last year." Then later we learn that the city had a population increase of 10% during the same year so the number of traffic accidents per person had actually gone down. Lies, damned lies and statistics...

Comment: @starball No, I don't know how to find that info at all. I have no idea how to use SEDE nor do I plan to learn it.

Comment: @HenryEcker I think you're right, it is based on actions performed by a person, but the suspensions are _implemented_ by the system, so they ought to be in the Community User column, IMO.

Comment: How many tasks entered the queues? How many close votes were cast?

Comment: FWIW, this is why I usually didn't try to split (system) community actions from (collective) community actions and (individual) community actions, @TylerH - it muddies the waters quite a bit in certain categories. The one area I found it useful to take the effort was deletion, as both author deletion and automated deletion account for huge portions of the total in every category; given the more detailed report for that isn't updated anymore, it's nice to see that split here!

Answer (score 6):

#### Questions

- Shiny new column! Any possibility of updating the previous year posts to have the Community User column? And how exactly is it split out? Is the old "Community" column a sum of the new "Community User" and "Community" columns?
- Out of curiosity, how do the counts get allocated if a user was a mod and then stopped being one in the middle of the year? Do the counts get split by which period the moderation action happened in? Or do they get indiscriminately placed in one of the categories?

#### Observations

Most numbers declined from last year. Not surprised given the [~2-month-long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/997587) [moderation strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/997587) and [general decline in content influx](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387278/997587).

Users contacted in 2022 was 8,487, and in 2023 was 11,217. Users suspended by mod in 2022 was 3,132, and in 2023 was 5,931. I expect it had to do with [the AIGC ban](/q/421831/11107541).

Comment: The effect of AI-generated content on those numbers is probably substantially larger than the raw numbers indicate. In late 2022-10, [the length of the automatic suspension applied for spam/troll profile destruction and "no longer welcome" profile deletion was increased to 365 days from 14 days](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/383399/271271). Prior to that, a very large percentage of the users who were destroyed/deleted for those two reasons would be automatically given a manual suspension of 365 days with a mod message as part of the userscripts we use.

Comment: After that system change, the userscripts were edited to no longer send the mod message with a 365-day suspension, rather just performing the profile deletion/destruction. The numbers of those userscript-automatic, manual mod-message with 365-day suspension for those profile destruction and deletion actions will have progressively been reduced as the userscripts were updated and users updated the copy they were using. Without the advent of easy AI-generated content in late 2022-11, I suspect the numbers you've mentioned would have declined dramatically in 2023.

Comment: Re *"Most numbers declined from last year"*: Yes, for instance, deleted posts dropped 35% (from 1.41 million to 1.04 million).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I haven't actually checked, but I assume that's just proportional to decline in post creation influx

Comment: @starball seems like it, yes. For questions: in 2022 there were 2 360 129 asked ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386090/2022-a-year-in-closing)) and in 2023 there were 1 489 399 asked ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396299/2023-a-year-in-closing)). This is 36.89% decline in questions. I'm not sure about answers but I suspect it'd be close - less questions does mean less things to answer.

Comment: In addition to the general decline, the proportion of reopened questions attributed to the community user is a really scary stat. That is votes from users who deleted there accounts, suggesting we potentially  lost roughly a quarter of the active reviewers in the reopen queue this year.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be possible to break down the question, answer and comment flags by reason? I'm also really curious how many of the custom flags mention some sort of `/\bAI(-?gen|GC|\b)|\b(chat-?)?GPT\b|\bLLM\b/i`.

Comment: I can tell you that of the roughly 4k raised-and-unhandled answer flags, half of them are mine and concern AIGC.

Comment: You would probably want to add "LLM" to that regex (example: "generated by a LLM"), and allow "GPT" as a word on its own (examples: "GPT generated", "a chat gpt answer").  Something like `/\b(AI(GC)?|(Chat.?)?GPT|LLM)\b/i`

Comment: on the gpt part, I assume `(chat-?)` was meant to be `(chat-?)?` ? (or else why the brackets?)

Comment: @starball oops, yes indeed. However all the regex optimisation is futile if nobody will run it on the data :-/

Answer (score 1):

I really think the *year in moderation* posts should include a breakdown like the one in [What posts get deleted, and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608)

With **1,048,164** posts deleted in 2023 there's no way to understand that number without going into more detail.

Also, it would be nice for users who contribute by casting deletion votes throughout the year to see their numbers put meaningfully into perspective.