# 2024 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15#questionnaire).**

---

Stack Overflow is scheduled for an election [next week, 2024-02-27](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here’s how it’ll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2024-02-27 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

  - How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
  - How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?
- The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

  - In your opinion, what do moderators do?
  - A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
  - In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching enough reputation to [access moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) or become a [trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user)?
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

  - We will post the final questionnaire on the [Election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15). Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
  - This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A. One such chatroom is provided [here](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256948).

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Considering that in the last 2 elections candidates have been called up at a later date, several moderators are absent, and the significant back log of flags, does [so] think that 2 candidates will be enough to lift this burden?

Comment: what is meant by "_In your opinion, what do moderators do?_"? I see a bit of what actions they perform, but other things they do are not public. Do mean more in a ideological sense like what Catija wrote in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396454/997587? Or something more literal like what privileges they have and what moderation actions they perform? (and what would it mean to have an opinion about that?)

Comment: @starball IMO, it's all of this. Or rather, the candidate should explain in their own words what they see what a moderator is and does.

Comment: I see it as more of a softball, philosophical question of what purpose do moderators serve, just stated in a less direct way to allow interpretation if someone wants to take it in another direction.

Comment: should "_Everything you will do will be_" instead say "Everything you have done will be", considering that that question start off talking about _past_ actions?

Comment: 2 is the number of candidates the current moderation team requested, @ThomA — they are closer to the ground than CMs are, so we generally go with the number suggested/requested by the moderation team, unless it seems wildly outlandish.

Comment: The idea of election is good, but I'd suggest backend administrators should replace the moderator position with AI architecture, this will be more efficient and proactive. I see a whole lot of duplicates and inappropriate comments, but it'll be tedious for only 2 moderators to pull this string. My 25 cents contribution.

Comment: @Dexter Duplicates are usually handled by the regular community member - with 3 close votes the question will be closed as a duplicate. Only 2 of the 3 need to be votes for a duplicate. It's somewhat similar for comments - if enough people flag them for removal, then the comment is automatically removed without needing a moderator to confirm it.

Answer (score 97):

At the time of writing this post, the flag queue consists of ~7000 “In need of moderator intervention flags”, the vast majority of which are about suspected AI-generated content.

If you get elected, you will **have to** sign the Moderator Agreement, which includes [the provisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391990/interim-policy-on-ai-content-detection-reports) resulting from the [June 2023 strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an). Per the Agreement, you **will not be allowed** to handle many, if not most, of those pending AI flags by deleting the post, because the post doesn’t meet company-approved heuristics for deletion.

Even though progress has been made on this front, such artificial constraints on flag handling have caused previously active moderators to go on permanent strike and are an ongoing source of frustration for everyone involved.

Why do you still want to become a moderator specifically under these conditions? How will you deal with the frustration — if any — of not being able to expediently deal with issues that the community cares about?

Comment: Does this accurately reflect the *status quo*? Some mods continue on strike because they're unsatisfied that not more posts can be deleted?

Comment: @bad_coder the question is ill-posed. I don’t know if those mods are striking “because they're unsatisfied that not more posts can be deleted”. You’d have to ask them. Anyway, the wording you chose makes it sound like those mods only want to delete stuff for the sake of deleting it, which would be an unfair and preposterous characterization. It’s more accurate to say that some mods feel unable to fulfill the community mandate because of the company actions. But again, I can’t speak for them. It’s just a fact that some didn’t find in the negotiations a sufficiently good compromise to come back

Comment: @blackgreen if I didn't express the comment better it's not because of any intention to misrepresent the issue. Quite the contrary, I was under the impression that the agreement between company and mods was to everyone's satisfaction regarding deletion of suspected ChatGPT generated content, so I am quite surprised -and it's the first I've heard- that not all mods have resumed activity due to continued dissatisfaction despite the new agreement/policy.

Comment: @bad_coder I'll reply to that using someone else's words, which get the point across better than I could: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations#comment1310487_391847

Comment: I mean, one could answer the candidate questionnaire with the objection: "I am indeed allowed to handle those flags, I can handle them without deleting the post!" though I would not vote for that candidate, then.

Comment: That leaves 3000 flags that can still be handled.

Comment: Can this be made shorter? I think the first three paragraphs could be condensed into 1–2 sentences. There's only a limited amount of characters available in a nomination for the questionnaire and its answers…

Comment: @Laurel in my nomination post, I'm going to be shortening this to `\[...\] you will not be allowed to handle \[most\] pending AI flags by deleting the post, because the post doesn’t meet company-approved heuristics for deletion. \[...\] Why do you still want to become a moderator specifically under these conditions? How will you deal with the frustration \[...\]?`

Comment: @starball That's fair. You could technically remove it entirely but it would make it harder to follow.

Comment: This question holds some truth.  I have unhandled ChatGPT flags from 6 months ago. I have absolutely no doubt they were generated by ChatGPT.

Answer (score 54):

Given recent developments on the site (and the network), especially in the past year, why do you want to run for moderator? What motivates you to serve this community, when many users openly object to moderation and the company's decisions sometimes seem at odds with moderator and community consensus?

Comment: "What developments? What happened?"

Comment: *"many users openly object to moderation"* Can you elaborate? Do you just mean newbies being grumpy when their questions get closed, or something else?

Answer (score 39):

There are likely to be enough questions proposed by the community to prevent the extra questions from the Community team from being added, and I think one of the questions from there is a good one, so I'm proposing a slight variation to be voted on:

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective than what you could do with the [access to moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools), [trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user), and other privileges?

Answer (score 34):

Modship has lost (more) charm recently.

- Users' perception of SO and site traffic continue to decline (in favour of ChatGPT).
- You have 4k+ AI-Generated Content (AIGC) flags waiting for you, for which the actioning rules are complicated and under slow development.
- Many think mods are power-hungry elitists. Now add "tech-luddite", and "SO should just embrace AIGC" to that.
- Some SO/SE members are fed up with SO Inc. To some, you are an egotistical company lapdog.

Despite the pain, perceptions, and work ahead of you, **why do *you* think this place is still worth it?** How does your perspective differ from the perspectives of all those people?

Comment: I don't see moderators as egotistical or power hungry, but I do always wonder why someone would currently sign up to a role where theres a high chance that the SOCorp would be putting them in the middle of moderating a policy that will be vehemently refuted.

Comment: This is a worthwhile read and a worthwhile question though, one that is outside of the traditional moderation box and that echoes some of my own thoughts. While classic moderation of the site is always needed, we also need to continue to elect individuals who will well represent and boost the interests of the community at large in their interactions with the company's representative.

Comment: I feel you have a really good question in the third-bullet regarding some outside *perception* of Moderators' motivations.  It's a question I've certainly asked myself in trying to determine whether or not I want to run.  Would you consider splitting that out separately?

Comment: hope you don't mind the edit. Maybe precede with **Suspected** AI-Generated Content (AIGC)

Comment: Real talk: Did it ever have charm to begin with? You essentially become a super-janitor and you'll immediately be the villain in every angrily made assumption, plus all your actions come under much higher scrutiny so you'll be explaining yourself frequently. It takes a special person to want to be a moderator on this site. The kind that sees a mountain of issues created by other people and then gets excited to go clean it up rather than exhausted. I have learned long ago that I will never escape the latter group :)

Comment: Could the second bullet be removed since, I believe, it is covered in [@blackgreen's question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428196/11810933)?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds actually, considering the current state of cottontail's question, I don't really see the point of this question being put in the pool anymore... it's a bit of a different angle, but enough of the same core.

Comment: @starball Ah, I guess.  Honestly I see "Why is the site still worth it?" and "What motivates you?" as different *enough*, but you're right that they are pretty close.  Are you planning on deleting the post then?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds \*sighs. I dunno. I personally want to remove this question from the pool now that cottontail's exists, but I don't want people coming after me angrily after they upvoted this. I'm just going to leave it up to the CMs to decide what they want to include.

Answer (score 20):

With the increasing number of moderators, it is expected to introduce more discrepancies in moderation. For example, a helpful flag may be marked as declined/disputed by another moderator with a different point of view.

Do you seek alignment in moderation with other moderators? If so, what will you propose to achieve alignment in moderation with other moderators?

Comment: This is a subtle variation of the standard question *"How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?"* but I feel it's very relevant because it puts emphasis on seeking alignment, instead of just dealing with a conflict after the fact. It's unfortunate it came in so late and will probably fail to accrue many upvotes. I hope the CMs will consider this for inclusion.

Comment: Increasing? I was under the impression that they are rapidly in decline, with many going inactive.

Answer (score 18):

Do you have any particular philosophies on moderation or curation that might set you apart from other candidates?

Answer (score 13):

A frequent answerer flags for moderator attention because a curating user persistently closes questions (rightfully as duplicate/off-topic) then posts comments under the answerer's posts to remind them to close close-able questions instead of posting an answer.

You investigate and find:

- The answerer (who has the privilege to flag/vote to close) has a history of frequently answering duplicate and off-topic questions which are later closed.
- The curator has a history of frequently posting reminding comments under the answerer's posts.
- There is definitive evidence that both parties are frustrated.

How will you handle such a situation to best serve the platform and its users?

Comment: For "transparency", => could maybe mention that this Answer relates to [this Thread/Feature-Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428038/3799241) and maybe more specifically to [this Comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428038/only-honor-reputation-earned-on-open-pages-when-calculating-collection-leaderboa#comment986511_428038) (to the same Question on MSO).

Comment: If I was being transparent, I'd state that I was recently suspended for repeatedly calling out a user with >200k and multiple hammers who was frequently answering new questions that I was closing with 5 duplicates.  This is a problem not confined to a single hyper-answering user though.

Comment: is the closing mentioned here primarily done via hammer by the same person who raised the flag? because mods aren't expected to be SMEs, including judging whether anything is a duplicate or not. how many samples were given in the flag message? has there been any discussion between high-rep users in the tag about whether those specific duplicate closures are appropriate? (or how else will the mod have confidence that what is reported is accurate if they aren't an SME in that topic?) if I were a non-SME mod looking at this, I'd want at least one (or maybe two) other SME to confirm duplication.

Comment: No, the flagger claiming to be the victim of abuse is not swinging their hammer(s) as they should.  I was hammering the questions being answered and these questions were such basic, mega-duplicates that I was able to find at least 5 earlier asked dupes (sometimes more and some of the dupes were dupes of dupes).  I do not know what was written in the flag to mods.  I think I should not give specific details about the proposed candidate question. I'd rather that candidates explain what they would do with this basic starting information and express their philosophies on the topic. @sta

Comment: @mickmackusa ah sorry. I got confused after reading your earlier comment. I got mixed up and thought it was the dup-closer mod-flagging asking for mods to deal with the answerer's persistent pattern of behaviour (something I have done before).

Answer (score 8):

What personality traits and/or technical skills do you have that you think will be useful in your modship? How did you come to acquire them (if relevant)?

Comment: (a bit more of a fun "get to know you" question)

Comment: Yeah are you a cat or a dog person? I only accept people who say "both".

Comment: Would you say please when asking a user to improve their question? Do you think you should say please? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328269/should-i-be-nice-to-new-users

Comment: @Gimby So the moderator has to have pointy ears, long teeth, a tongue constantly sticking out, nine lives and fast legs? And able to squeeze in everywhere? And be coated in thick fur? And bark at everyone that passes them?

Comment: @AndreasmovedtoCodidact so you have met that moderator too!

Comment: @AndreasmovedtoCodidact Now we're talking!

Answer (score 7):

Do you expect that earning a diamond would change your rate of posting questions/answers and, if so, why would that be?

Comment: I am curious why this would matter to you? Why does the continued rate of posting questions/answers matter for diamond moderators on StackOverflow? They already need to have a pretty high reputation just to nominate themselves, let alone get elected.

Comment: @Nike I want to see the nominee's thoughts and reasoning of how well they've considered how taking up a moderator's mantle would affect them. IMO, this would demonstrate how much they have considered this new power and responsibility would have an impact on their pre-diamond engagement with the site.

Comment: Hey, I know where you came up with that one ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow [currently bans genAI usage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned), but different people have a variety of opinions on the policy as-is and what it should look like.

Do you think anything should be changed about that policy? If so, what?

Comment: I don't love this question because it seems to imply that moderators get to pick site policy. They generally don't (at least not individually), and _especially_ don't about AI. That aside, if I ran, I would answer this by saying "I would disallow all questions about genAI, programming or otherwise", but that's obviously not going to happen even I got elected. So what's the benefit of asking this in determining whether a user is a good moderator candidate?

Comment: @KevinB was the [AI ban](/revisions/421831/1) not set by mods?

Comment: @TylerH That's a good point. My intention wasn't to imply that mods can set policy at all but rather to gauge how candidates feel about the AI policy, as that could help inform voters about how candidates think about AI on SO. Feel free to edit this if you have ideas on how the phrasing could be improved to be more clear about that.

Comment: mods did ban AI use because AI use pretty much _entirely_ flouted other rules on the site that already existed (attribution/authorship rules). Then the company overruled the mods because the CEO/board wants the company to look friendly to AI rather than the opposite.

Comment: @starball We set the original policy but [there were complications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424979/what-has-happened-to-lead-moderators-to-consider-striking). We don't have full control over the policy making. TBH, a lot of that policy seems to be set in the AI Team(s) at present. We wouldn't have 7k mod flags if we were in full control of the policy

Answer (score 5):

As a moderator, how will you ensure that SO remains useful and welcoming for users and, in particular, new users?

---

Context: I'm new here myself. I experience (part of) SO as a demanding environment and learned that it has a reputation for being so.

However, I believe that SO + other SEs are important, even more so in the future.

It seems that moderators have a few loyalties here (fellow existing moderators, a company—where some of the senior staff seem to use the page only occasionally themselves—and users). Keeping existing users engaged and making SO more welcoming for *helpful* new users seems very important to me to ensure the long term future of this site.

Comment: I don't think moderators per se can ensure SO remains useful. At best they can keep the community at track once the community decided they want SO to remain useful. There are way more folks with pitchforks on Meta then there are moderators.

Comment: The onus is not on existing Stack Overflow users to be welcoming to new users. It is on new users to prove they are worthy of becoming part of this community. Respect is earned, not freely given.

Comment: The site is too "welcoming", IMO. It contradicts with the giant pile of rules we have, a lot of which can lead to people losing privileges. If anything, people need to learn what it means to be welcome.

Comment: Moderators _do_ have a role in ensuring the site is welcoming to new users.  It's possible to be welcoming to new users while still upholding high standards (after all, the users contributing quality content were once new themselves).  Of course, our ability to do so is somewhat limited compared to what, say, better onboarding would do, but...

Comment: @RyanM we all do, since the site owners don't (successfully) facilitate it. I have seen a few occasions on the Discussions feature where people were asking for help to ask a question on the Q&A site. At least that is something that could be stimulated more.

Answer (score 4):

You receive a flag on an answer.  The flag is valid (e.g., it is indeed a link-only answer).  Do you leave a comment inviting the user to improve their answer, or do you delete the answer straight away?  How do you choose between acting immediately vs leaving comments to encourage users to improve their posts?

Comment: I don't know if this is a good question. On a scale of SO, leaving comments on each post we handle is impossible. We handle way too many flags.

Comment: To put it a different way [mods handled more than 178,000 answer flags in 2023](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427863/2023-a-year-in-moderation). What you're proposing is we leave a comment and circle back later to see if they listened. There's no easy way to do that at the volume of flags we get.

Comment: @Machavity, I'm sorry if it came off that way.  Absolutely not, I'm not proposing that.  I attempted to word the question neutrally but I was thinking that the answers might be informative for me about whether candidates know what they are getting in for, and are aware why it won't work to leave a comment and come back later.  No criticism of mods intended in any way.

Comment: @D.W. None taken. We're just trying to tell you how the site works in practice. We've even had CMs who underestimated how much effort it takes to "go the extra mile". We just don't have the time, sadly.

Comment: @Machavity, yup, I already knew that, and the reason I proposed the question is to probe whether candidates were aware of that.

Comment: I think you have a good question in there, just perhaps not phrased the right way yet.  You can [Edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/428192/edit) your question to improve it, or alternatively you can self-flag it for Moderator removal .  In all seriousness, though - It's a concern I've had for a long time in determining whether or not I wanted to be a moderator on any of the SE sites I frequent. I *prefer* to leave a comment, and if I were a Moderator I'd probably still *try* to, at least initially.  But I also trust the existing Moderators that it's almost certainly unsustainable :-/

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, thank you for the encouragement, can you offer any assistance in improving it (perhaps by suggesting an edit) or suggesting changes to how it is phrased?

Comment: @D.W. Honestly, the question looks pretty good to me. I was semi-joking in the first part of my comment, simply based on other's comments.  I'm not sure about improving it, but maybe incorporate the "reality" that Dharman and Machavity noted in there as part of the dilemma that Mod candidates will face?  FWIW, I upvoted it as it stands.

Comment: @Machavity: presumably the 'right' answer on this one is: tend to delete if the user doesn't have a track record of improving their answers and/or link is VLQ, borderline spammy or not to an authoritative source; leave, if the user does have a track record of improving their answers and the link is to an authoritative source. D.W. it's a mistake to set up the question as a one-size-fits-all 'preference'.

Comment: @smci, Thank you for the feedback.  See revised answer.  Hopefully "How do you...?" opens the stage for a candidate to list what factors would influence their decision, if they wouldn't always make the same decision.

Comment: Ok but "it is indeed a link-only answer" can mean almost anything. If it's a link to the language's own reference doc, then we don't suspect the respondent's motives at all; if it's a link to SEO-juice blog/ low-quality tutor site/ plagiarism, then it's something else.

Comment: @smci, Sure.  The critical part is "the flag is valid".  If you can't answer the question based on the information listed, feel free to elaborate on how you'd approach different situations or how you'd think about it.  My goal is not to focus on a single specific situation/scenarios, but to learn something about candidates.  If you have a concrete suggestion about how to improve the question I'm glad to hear it.  At this point I suspect it might be moot given the late date, but I welcome suggestions for improvement.

Comment: @D.W. I understand your intent, but this isn't a very representative example, I almost never see cases like that. The much more common case, which is also less clearcut, is a low-quality question, not enough effort, no or incomplete MCVE, symptom not explained, new or low-rep user, especially when the question is a likely duplicate (although often questions are so vague we can't tell). So in that case we can't even definitively tell whether the "the flag is valid" without putting in lotta effort. But this is the use-case which SO corporate is trying to encourage.

Comment: @smci, If you have actionable suggestions on how to improve the question -- specifically, suggested wording -- I welcome it.  (Do note that I'm talking about flag handling -- flagging for moderator review is normally not the appropriate method to handle the situation you mentioned.  I'm very sympathetic to concerns about question quality, but that is not what my proposed question is about.)  If you don't have concrete wording suggestions, I accept your opinion and do not plan on taking any further action.

Answer (score 0):

A gold badge holder marks a question as a duplicate.  Another re-opens it and answers it.  This might continue back and forth for a while, between closure and re-opening.  You receive one or more flags asking that the question be re-closed or re-opened.  How would you handle this?

Comment: Users can only close-vote or re-open vote a question _once_, so this situation would require multiple gold badge owners to disagree like that... I've seen that happen maybe once, and that question was then brought to Meta to discuss... So, what I'm trying to say, this doesn't seem like a realistic scenario a mod would encounter that much.

Comment: @Cerbrus Er... this happens more than you would think. Yes, you have limited close votes, but there are groups of folks who work together (and I don't mean SOCVR) to ensure questions wind up in the state they want.

Answer (score -5):

Let's have a discussion, collectively.

Collectives are this weird bolt-on feature with overlaps on Q&A but also these other content options like Articles and Discussion. Given the current state of moderation tooling and guidance you can at best keep the Q&A at check and leave the rest to SE staff or their appointees.

At some point in time friction arises between the much leeway collectives have and the Q & As that you moderate. You're asked by a fair amount of tag subject matter experts who  haven't joined the said collective to send a strong moderation signal that boundaries have been over-stepped.

What arguments will you use to convince the Company, their customer and others involved that the collective has to step up their quality game and stick to established consensus on curation to guarantee their Q and A will not be removed on sight?

Comment: That’s.. not how collectives work? Questions don’t belong to collectives.

Comment: @KevinB that might be, still there is this indication that questions are part of a collective tag and it is answered by a collective member. The overlap is what I foresee the tention on (also because I envision an SO that has no public Q/A anymore, only collectives)

Answer (score -6):

In 2023 [moderators across the network went on strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811) due to announced and unannounced changes by the Company.

Are you going to strike for me in 2024 and beyond? Why?

*a more subtle variant of this question was proposed by user cottontail  [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428195)*

Comment: I don't think that was the point of cottontail's question? seems like a weird question to ask, or a weird way to phrase whatever you're probably trying to get at. obviously there needs to be a reason to strike. so are you really asking for what reasons the nominee would go on strike?

Comment: It seems pretty pointless to become a moderator only to not act as a moderator. Surely you did not intend to ask whether new moderators won't moderate, but it seems that any positive reply amounts to that. Perhaps you can [edit] the question to clarify what you are trying to get at?

Comment: I don't think it is a strange question. I just don't expect anyone would feel comfortable answering it honestly during elections :) It is worth knowing how willing a person is to join a strike. It all depends on what you expect moderators to represent.

Answer (score -11):

You made a moderation related decision against a new user.  The new user disputed it in Meta. The community overwhelmingly agreed and applauded your decision. However upon contemplating overnight, it is abundantly clear that the decision you took was not right and the right thing to do would be to reverse it.

At least half of your fellow moderators agree that the initial decision is not right according to current policies, but that practically, there would be very little gain to the community from reversing it and the only gain would be to the new user.  You are sure you would lose support among established community members and fellow users, if you were to reverse it. You'll also be seen as being double minded and unable to take a decision with confidence or follow through on it - characteristics seen as unfit for a moderator. Your future decisions might also be questioned.

Given such risks of personal reputation loss and very little profit to the current community, would you still attempt to reverse the decision, for the sake of the new user? If so, why? If not, why? And how would you go about it?

Comment: It's a convoluted setup with a lot of assumptions; which basically boils down to: "Would you do what you think is right, or bend down to imaginary social pressure?". Not entirely sure what one is supposed to learn from answers to this.

Comment: Why would a mod realizing that they've made a mistake reflect badly on the mod? It would be seen as a good thing if they were to admit a mistake (assuming they don't happen all the time), and took the trouble to fix it.

Comment: The question doesn't just deal with social pressure. For eg, It deals with the action that the moderator would take, when they fail, as humans do. Double down or retract? It deals with what they would do when established meta members like yourself want to go one way and they want to go another way. Would they push through or try to convince? And what would they do when there is no profit to the community, but just the little guy? Are they willing to bet on the little guy for future profit of the community?  The intricacies of the convoluted setup deals not just with Mod integrity, but...[1/2]

Comment: The problem is that, at least as you've phrased it, there is an obvious correct answer.  You don't learn anything from someone saying "If given a choice between doing the right thing and doing the wrong thing, I would do the right thing."

Comment: ...on practical actions and how they profit the community.  While the leading question points to "help the new user", I don't believe there is only one correct answer to this. I'm more interested in the  thought process of the moderator and the justification of the moderator decision, if they were to take such a decision[2/2]

Comment: @RyanM addressed in the second comment( Without even reading yours)   :) Even if they were give  the answer(that the question is leading to), the "why" is more important than "the correct answer". I believe We can learn more about the candidate as a person from  such an answer.

Answer (score -15):

How can, or rather why should, the good people and users of Stack Overflow, *ergo "the community" writ-large*, feel confident that you can not only maintain your current work-life balance but deal with the expected additional burden that may very well indeed occur if you were to become a moderator and do said job as expected or perhaps beyond?

*(which includes not only the expected time or schedule aspect but also the largely non-discussed mental and emotional aspect of realizing the palpable actions [or inaction] of your discretion and judgement may impact real people just like you and me adversely and unfairly, including all the possibilities thereof, no matter how remote, of poor and unwarranted moderator actions ie. discouraging a potential great mind from pursuing what would have otherwise been a great life that changes the world for the better, upsetting someone who views software and related development as their last shot in life who then goes off and does who knows what to who knows who, etc.)*

That's a fair and succinct, above all pertinent, question. I'd say.

Comment: _"succinct"_ this question certainly isn't.

Answer (score -17):

What do you want to gain from being elected as a moderator in Stack Overflow?

Comment: The only objectively correct answer here is "Access to the exclusive mod tools. Because it must be the best UX there, if it is that restricted." :P

Comment: You can only gain having less free time and having less hair.

Comment: There is only one answer: Power! What else?

Comment: A better broom, duh.

Comment: I get that some of the comments are joking, but I am not sure if all of them are joking. So, I would like to point out that there is not only 1 answer to this question even though this question looks simple. One can gain experience, self-esteem, hobby, knowledge, and even reputation out of being a moderator in SO. I for one would want to be a moderator to gain some of those, and even extend to gaining social connections. I wouldn't dare volunteer though for now, I am still not qualified. I just still think that my question on this post is not that bad. Still, I could be wrong.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's as bad as the voting reflects, either (perhaps the phrasing could be better...?).  The biggest issue, I think, is that it's essentially "why do you want to be a moderator?", which hopefully the candidate addresses in their introduction.  I've proposed [a more specific variation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428197/208273) focusing on gains related to ability to improve the site, which seems to be better received.

Comment: I agree - The question itself is not bad IMHO, but the "stock" version of the question that @RyanM proposed, I believe, is better worded and should elicit the same general responses.

Comment: Indeed. This is essentially a duplicate question that is so simplified that it reads suggestive. "Come on. Admit that this is about gaining clout". There is nothing here that would prevent me from interpreting it like that and in fact I would say that it is written to trigger me to interpret it like that. Waste a few more words on us please, give it context.