# Community Bot is actively participating in question reopening

Tags: discussion, support, community-user, reopen-review

There is an interesting Reopen votes review showing that Community Bot actively participated in reopening a question. Not only that, the question was reopened only by two votes where it usually takes three.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26342915

The question falls into the highly active category, but that does not mean it should be automatically reopened. It was closed by a mod and its history shows that it was left closed in review 7 times.

Why and how is Community Bot involved in Reopen Queue?

Comment: This is so annoying, I saw a question 10yrs old and the only activity had been by the Community Bot but I couldn't see any edits or comments (I'm not digging into Review Queue's). This needs to be addressed.

Comment: Yesterday also seen it having deleted a question posted as an answer, with a completely non-matching reason... the delete was correct, but the AI needs a whole lot more training to come anywhere close to a human being.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Read the posted answer, it was not the AI, but regular user that removed the account in the meantime.

Comment: @MartinZeitler the Community user does not use AI to delete content.  Do you happen to have a link to the post you're referring to?

Comment: @JeremyThompson That is completely different from what Dalija is asking about here. What you are talking about is [the Community user randomly "bumping" old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285978/community-modified-posts-appearing-on-homepage).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's not. [The user who reviewed was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/148747/revisions), and Community took ownership of the review. Community takes ownership of quite a lot when users are removed, and it seems like reviews is one of those things.

The timeline also shows a third reopen vote from a user prior to either of the two from the review queue; reopen votes can originate outside the queue both before, during, and after a review. In this case, a reopen vote triggered the review.

Nothing out of the ordinary here.

Comment: Precisely. For what it's worth, the voting user's account was *self-deleted*, not removed by a moderator for rule violations.

Comment: I see. I somehow missed the latest entry in the history showing three users. I guess Community Bot entry confused me enough.

Comment: It is, admittedly, a sub-par UI. Why do the review queue tasks not just show the name of the deleted user account, just as the revisions/timeline does?

Comment: @CodyGray A logical UI? Sorry, you're in the wrong place for that

Comment: "Sub-par", where local standards define "par". It was a relative comparison to other UIs that exist on this very site.

Comment: Background info (for all): *[Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/)*

Comment: When we are at sub-par UI. I tried to accept the answer two times, but it was too soon. And then I almost forgot about it. I wouldn't be surprised that some of the questions were never accepted because people just move on to another thing and forget to go back.

Comment: Eventually community would take all that it has absorbed and become sentient, if not for the fact that it's a constant.

Comment: The version my mind came out with of Community Bot gaining self-awareness and becoming a troll was funnier